# Bing Maps REST api - Where can I find more detailed information concerning error messages?

Tags: bing-maps

I've already checked out [their page on error handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701703.aspx) but all it has is descriptions of the status codes a request may return. Does bing provide information one what will be returned if I have exceeded the number of requests allowed per day?

Answer (score 1):

If you have exceeded the number of request per day, there might be an information included in your response header. It must fit with the limitations described in the terms of use.

See at the bottom of the page you linked, tell us what you got from here:

> Responses that do not return results
>
> Occasionally, the servers processing service requests can be
>   overloaded, and you may receive some responses that contain no results
>   for queries that you would normally receive a result. To identify this
>   situation, check the HTTP headers of the response. If the HTTP header
>   X-MS-BM-WS-INFO is set to 1, it is best to wait a few seconds and try
>   again.

Comment: I have no exceeded the number of requests per day yet, I'm just trying to anticipate what that will look like and prepare some kind of logging for that event.

Comment: You will have an empty response content and the http header in the response set to 1. What you can do on your side, is also to count the number of request per 24h period (as well as for year period).